# Add a bootstrap class to JS class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a small question,

At the moment I have a 2 option boxes in my Test.php file. I want to show my second option box when I select leverancier in the first one. so far so good!
But now I want to apply some CSS to it...
for example the bootstrap form-control class...

this is my (simple) code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#corracrtieby").on("change", function() {
            var select_val = $(this).val();
            console.log(select_val);
            if (select_val === 'Leverancier') {
                $("#Klanttable").removeClass("hidden");
            }
            else {
                $("#Klanttable").addClass("hidden");
                $("#Klanttable").val("");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Correctie maatregelen:<br>
<select name="corracrtieby" class="form-control" id="corracrtieby" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="--corracrtieby--">--corracrtieby--</option>
    <option value="Petrogas">Petrogas</option>
    <option value="Leverancier">Leverancier</option>
    <option value="Klant">Klant</option>
</select>
<br>

<select name="Klanttable" class="hidden" id="Klanttable" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="--Klanttable--">--Correctie maatregel--</option>
    <option value="Test1">Petrogas</option>
    <option value="Test2">Leverancier</option>
    <option value="Test3">Klant</option>
    <option value="Test4">Klant</option>
    <option value="Test5">Klant</option>
</select>
```

So how can I make my first option box the same as my second option box?

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery you can add multiple classes at once so your solution would just be:

```
$(function() {
    $("#corracrtieby").on("change", function() {
        var select_val = $(this).val();
        console.log(select_val);
        if (select_val === 'Leverancier') {
            $("#Klanttable").removeClass("hidden form-control");
        }
        else {
            $("#Klanttable").addClass("hidden form-control");
            $("#Klanttable").val("");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: But where can I add my form-control class then

Comment: the from-control is behind the hidden class in,   .addClass("hidden form-control");

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#corracrtieby").on("change", function() {
            var select_val = $(this).val();
            console.log(select_val);
            if (select_val === 'Leverancier') {
                $("#Klanttable").removeClass("hidden form-control");
            }
            else {
                $("#Klanttable").addClass("hidden form-control");
                $("#Klanttable").val("");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

Correctie maatregelen:<br>
<select name="corracrtieby" class="form-control" id="corracrtieby" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="--corracrtieby--">--corracrtieby--</option>
    <option value="Petrogas">Petrogas</option>
    <option value="Leverancier">Leverancier</option>
    <option value="Klant">Klant</option>
</select>
<br>

<select name="Klanttable" class="hidden form-control" id="Klanttable" style="width: 300px">
    <option value="--Klanttable--">--Correctie maatregel--</option>
    <option value="Test1">Petrogas</option>
    <option value="Test2">Leverancier</option>
    <option value="Test3">Klant</option>
    <option value="Test4">Klant</option>
    <option value="Test5">Klant</option>
</select>
```

now it's removing only the class, not the option box itself......